# Ruby Runtime Error Frozen Fixnum

Tags: ruby, runtime-error

While using Ruby 2.0 I am getting the following error, and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
class Numeric
  @@currencies = {'yen' => 0.013, 'euro' => 1.292, 'rupee' => 0.019, 'dollar' => 1}
  def method_missing(method_id)
    singular_currency = method_id.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')
    @src_currency = singular_currency
    if @@currencies.has_key?(singular_currency)
      self * @@currencies[singular_currency]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def in(dst_currency)
    (1 / @@currencies[dst_currency.to_s.gsub( /s$/, '')]) * self
  end
end

p 5.dollars.in(:euros)
p 10.euros.in(:rupees)
```

This throws an error:

```
`method_missing': can't modify frozen Fixnum (RuntimeError)
```

I looked around and I kind of understand what is going on here, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What line is throwing that error?

Comment: you're adding an instance variable to a Numeric instance. You can't do that

Comment: First, don't mix code with error messages. Comment the first line, at least.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simplified example of the error:

```
class Numeric
  def add_an_instance_variable
    @foo = 1
  end
end

 5.add_an_instance_variable
```

This is because `Fixnum`s are frozen and you're not allowed to modify them.

The reason for this is that [Fixnums are special](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html):

> Fixnum objects have **immediate value**. This means that when they are
>   assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather
>   than a reference to that object.
>
> Assignment does not alias Fixnum objects. There is effectively only
>   one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value, so, for
>   example, you cannot add a singleton method to a Fixnum. Any attempt to
>   add a singleton method to a Fixnum object will raise a TypeError.

Immediate Objects are explained in detail in the [Programming Ruby Book](http://ruby.activeventure.com/programmingruby/book/ext_ruby.html)

---

When you want your numbers to store what currency they're in you'll need to wrap them in their own class.

(don't reinvent the [Money Gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). It's good. You can probably use it)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line `@src_currency = singular_currency`. Get rid of the "@" and you should be good to go.

What the error msg is telling you is that you are trying to modify the frozen Fixnum (by assigning an instance variable to it)